# How to get installed extension ids using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm going to check whether IDM chrome extension is installed or not.
So I used chrome API.

chrome.runtime.sendMessage("lcdlanlaneooailnebnhamiiieebikid", "message", function(e){
isIDMinstalled = true;
})

"lcdlanlaneooailnebnhamiiieebikid"  // IDM extension id

but callback function is called although chrome extension is not installed.

Comment: See sample in "Cross-extension messaging" Chrome dev page: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external

Comment: Use `chrome.management` API. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/)

Comment: I tried chrome.management api, but chrome doesnt have management key.

Comment: It's undefined value